# ActionLink to HttpPost action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have this link on my page:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Like", "Like", "Like", new {likeId = i.ItemId}, new {id = @i.ItemId, @class = "likeButton"})
```

This is my ajax call:

```
$(document).on("click", ".likeButton", function (event) {

        var itemId = event.target.id;

        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { item: itemId },
            context: this,
            success: function (result) {
                ...
        return false;
    });
```

And it works when action metohd is like:

```
public ActionResult Like(int itemId)
...
```

But if I decorate method with `[HttpPost]` It doesn't work. 
Can this be achieved?
Also what security issue can be if I don't add `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: you are looking for 'int itemId', why you pass item: 'data: { item: itemId }' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".likeButton", function (event) {

    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'POST',
        context: this,
        success: function (result) {
            ...
    return false;
});
```

You are passing item.Id twice, first in url and second in body. when using post method, you can still pass parameters through url. passing parameters with body is good when you want to hide these parameters.

And one more thing, you can use Ajax.ActionLink in this case (because it is created for this kind of cases)

And you have mistake:

```
data: { item: itemId }
```

Should be:

```
data: { itemId: itemId },
```

Comment: Yes, the problem gone when I removed 'data' from function.